# dc.js: show all domain x values in heatmap

Tags: heatmap, dc.js, crossfilter

**Requirement**

I'm trying to create a heatmap indicating the frequency of an event through the hours of the week. On the Y axis I have the days of the week and on the X axis I have the hours of the day. I want to see all the hours of the day on the X axis, even those that do not have any corresponding frequency.

**Problem**

Unfortunately I'm not able to find out a way to display all the hours of the day. The Crossfilter includes only the hours of the day with a corresponding frequency during the week.

**Current graphic result**

[image]

As you can see not all hours of the day are displayed.

**Code**

```
let name = [
        '0', // S
        '6', // M
        '5', // T
        '4', // W
        '3', // T
        '2', // F
        '1' // S
];

this.heatmapDimension= this.data_CrossfilterObject.dimension((d) => {
            return [+d.hour, d.day + '.' + name[d.day]];
        });

this.heatmapGroup= this.heatmapDimension.group().reduceSum((d) => d));

this.giornoOraDashboardItem.chart
        .dimension(this.heatmapDimension)
        .group(this.heatmapGroup)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heatmap allows you to specify the x and y domains using [.cols()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/HeatMap.html#cols__anchor) and [.rows()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/HeatMap.html#rows__anchor) respectively.

It [doesn't work for filtering out data](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1516) but it does work for making sure that rows/columns exist.

In your case, since you are generating a string value for the y/row dimension, it would look like:

```
.rows(d3.range(7).map(i => i + '.' + name[i]))
.cols(d3.range(24))
```

[image: heatmap with assured columns]

Here is a [demo fiddle with random data](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/Lusmpvg0/49/).

#### Using day names

Update: since your intention is to show day names, here is one way to do that.

Day names:

```
let name = [
        'Su',
        'M',
        'Tu',
        'W',
        'Th',
        'F',
        'Sa'
];
```

Use the name directly in the dimension key accessor (no numeric prefix needed):

```
const heatmapDimension= cf.dimension((d) => {
        return [d.hour, name[d.day]];
    });
```

Specify the names, in reverse order, as the rows, and disable sorting of rows:

```
.rows(name.reverse()).rowOrdering(null)
```

(Reverse order is needed because the chart's zero is at the bottom.)

[image: screenshot with day names]

[New fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/Lusmpvg0/58/).

Comment: you made my day! Thank you so much!